# Linksys EA6300 extra SSID?

Tags: wireless-access-point

It seems that a LinkSys EA6300 (running as access point only) exposes an extra SSID without a name on the same channel as the configured 2,4 GHz network.

Checking it out with Wifi Analyzer for android I see that the real SSIDs are indicated as "CISCO CONSUMER PRODUCTS, LLC" but the third and odd SSID is indicated as "". It has no name and is protected with WPA2.

What is this network for, and can it be disabled? I assume that it is possibly interfering with the real network on the same channel?

Answer (score 0):

Under Apps, click Guest Access. Your guest network, which was set up
during your router installation, is displayed.
• To turn guest access on or off, click the Allow guest access button.
• The guest network name is based on your 2.4 GHz network name and
is automatically generated.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. We must have different software, as I do not have "Apps". Under wifi I have 2.4 and 5 GHz enabled, but no guest networks as far as I can see. The router is running as access point (bridge) only.